# Internal css doesn't work for me with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use the following css code in the table I create in JS but it seems that it doesn't get any of it's styles and I don't know why.

So here's the code:
CSS Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.team
    {
        margin-right: 30%;
    }
    .team table
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .team table td
    {
        background-color: #4F5FAC;
        border: 2px groove grey;
    }
    .team table th
    {
        font-style: italic;
        background-color: #0B1260;
        padding: 0 15px;
        color: white;
        border: 2px groove black;
    }
    .team tr td:first-child
    {
        color: yellow;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

JS code:

```
myWindow=window.open('table.html');
myWindow.document.write("<table class = 'team'>");
myWindow.document.write("<tr><td> שם  פרטי: </td><td>" + document.reg.name.value + "</td></tr> <tr><td> שם משפחה: " + document.reg.lname.value + "</td></tr> <tr><td> אימייל: " + document.reg.email.value + "</td></tr> <tr><td> סיסמא: " +document.reg.password.value +"</td></tr>");
myWindow.document.write("</table>");
```

Any idea why I don't get the styles of the table?(it works without the js)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see at least four issues:

1. The CSS rules have to be in the same document that you're trying to affect.  So these CSS rules would need to be in `table.html`.
2. If you use `document.write()` after the document has been loaded which you are doing here, it then clears out the current document (including all style rules you've previously included) and starts a new document.  So, there is no way for these style rules to be in effect in the `table.html` file because you've cleared out the prior contents of that document.  If you want to ADD content to the existing page without destroying it's current contents and styles, then you need to use DOM insertion API calls like `.append()` or `.insertBefore()` or set `.innerHTML` on an existing DOM object.
3. Your CSS rules are not specified properly.  When you are targeting multiple identifiers on the same tag, you cannot have a space between the identifiers.  So, `.team table` needs to be `table.team` and `.team table th` would need to be: `table.team th`.  When you have a space between identifiers as in `.team table`, that means you want to match a `table` object with an ancestor of `class="team"`.  If you want an object that is both a `table` and `class="team"`, then you have to not have a space between the two identifiers like this: `table.team`.
4. If you want to add content to this new window while keeping the contents of `table.html`, you will have to wait for it to load (with the `onload()` event or one of the other `DOMReady` events) before its contents are ready to be modified and you cannot use `document.write()`.

To solve all this, I would suggest this:

1. Put all the style rules in an external stylesheet and include them in table.html.
2. Put the javascript for modifying the page into table.html also.
3. When you load table.html, add query parameters onto the end of the URL that pass it the values you want to display in that file.
4. Add javascript to table.html that parses the query parameters to get the data and then, once the DOM is ready in that page, add that relevant content to the page.

This puts style rules in the right file and passes data to the new page while keeping the code for modifying the page within its own page (massively simplifying maintenance going forward).

---

OK, assuming you don't need any of the content in table.html, you can create a new window from scratch with this code:

```
function openMyWindow() {
    var newWin = window.open("", "table");
    newWin.document.write("<div class='team'>");
    newWin.document.write('<table>');
    newWin.document.write("<tr><td> שם  פרטי: </td><td>" + 
        document.reg.name.value + "</td></tr> <tr><td> שם משפחה: " + 
        document.reg.lname.value + "</td></tr> <tr><td> אימייל: " + 
        document.reg.email.value + "</td></tr> <tr><td> סיסמא: " + 
        document.reg.password.value +"</td></tr>");
    newWin.document.write("</table>");
    newWin.document.write("</div>");
    var cssLink = newWin.document.createElement("link") 
    cssLink.href = "iframestylefile.css"; 
    cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink.type = "text/css";     
    newWin.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssLink);
}​
```

You can see this work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/VLt8h/.  The style rules won't apply there because the css file doesn't have the correct full URL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer, but the following code is still not working for me:http://pastebin.com/4fcz9wSd

Comment: @idish - Apparently, you didn't understand points #2 and #4 in my answer.  You still aren't doing those.  Also, when you append style rules, they should be appended to the head tag, not the body tag.

Comment: I don't know how I can add these to the head tag from a window.open method, can you give me please a code sample?

Comment: If you control `table.html`, just add `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="registrationtable.css"/>` to the `<head>` section of that file.  There is no reason I'm aware of to be adding this via JS.

Comment: @idish - You aren't doing any of the things I've asked you to do so there's not much else I can do to help.  I've offered my advice and you aren't following it.  If you don't understand something I wrote, ask me questions about it, but don't do something different from what I suggested you do and then ask me why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think I understand, point 2, I just haven't learnt it yet that's why, and our teacher doesn't like when we add things that we haven't learnt, if I will use only document.write method once then it will work?

Comment: If you're tired of me, I will understand that. I'll just accept your answer then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9018/discussion-between-idish-and-jfriend00)

Comment: Let's back up a step.  Is there any HTML in `table.html` that you need to keep?  Or can you just open a blank window and write the content into it?  Or can you edit `table.html`?

Comment: I added a simpler version that creates the whole window from scratch.

Comment: I need to open a blank window and write content to it.

Comment: Listen, I very thankful for your helping me, and keep explaining me what I'm doing wrong, I really have to go now so really thank you very much! I appreciate this.

Comment: @idish - The code I added to the end of my answer does that.  You must add the style rules AFTER you do the document.write() statements like I have it shown.  You can see it work in the demo app.

Answer (score 1):

CSS `<style>` elements only apply to the page they're in. You're opening a completely new page. It will need its own copy of the CSS.

You could give the `<style>` element an "id" and then copy it.

```
<style id='page-style'> ... </style>
```

Then:

```
var myWindow=window.open('table.html');
myWindow.document.write('<style>' + document.getElementById('page-style').innerHTML + '</style>');
// ... your code to build the table
```

On Internet Explorer, I think you'll need "innerText" instead of "innerHTML".

Keeping the style in a separate stylesheet is probably better anyway.

Comment: I see, what is the solution for this then?

Comment: You'll need to copy the `<style>` element from the source page into the new page.

Comment: create seprate css file and use in table.html

Comment: Alright, thank you I'll try that, it seems to be the right answer.

Comment: This is only one of the many issues.  And, you can't immediately open a new window when specifing table.html and starting writing into it unless you intend to clear the current document.  One has to wait for the document to load and then append to the DOM, not document.write() to the DOM to preserve table.html.  My answer goes into all the various issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use double quotes ("") for your team class.

Comment: Single quotes are fine in HTML.

Comment: just try that. may it work. have u checked with different browser

Answer (score 0):

#### You **CANNOT** apply style to another page with the CSS of one page.

Upload the CSS to a file, then use the following snippet to load the css onto the opened page.

```
myWindow=window.open('table.html');
var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
cssLink.href = "iframestylefile.css"; 
cssLink .rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink .type = "text/css"; 
myWindow.document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
// Now carry on writing the elements
```